# How to pull JSON information to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a permit tracking sheet and I am having issues pulling information from a public JSON to google sheets and formatting it with script editor. I am relatively new to coding and could use any help. The Code is kind of a Frankenstein of different things I found on Stack Overflow and other sites.

```
function pullPermits() {

  // Call the Permit API to get Permit infrmation
  var permits = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  var events = permits.getString();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = [["Uniquekey","Application Name","Application Status","Application Start Date","Application End Date","Primary Contact Last","Application Name", "Street Number From", "Street Number To","Direction","Street Name","Suffix", "Application Processed Date","Comments","Detail"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,15);

  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
  var row=i+2;

  range.setValues(header);

  var details=[[permits,events[i].getUniquekey(), events[i].getApplicationname(), events[i].getApplicationstatus(), events[i].getApplicationstartdate(), events[i].getApplicationenddate(), events[i].getPrimarycontactlast(), events[i].getApplicationname(), events[i].getStreetnumberfrom(), events[i].getStreetnumberfrom(), events[i].getDirection(), events[i].getStreetname(), events[i].getSuffix(), events[i].getApplicationprocesseddate(),events[i].getComments,()events[i].getDetails()]];
  var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,15);
range.setValues(details);
}
```

Receiving Syntax error

Comment: What's your traceback?

Comment: Could you include the error you encountered?

Comment: Syntax Error in the line containing var details

Comment: @pizzapuff I thought that your script is Google Apps Script and you are actually using Google Apps Script from your reply comment. So I modified the tag. And I think that the reason of the error is ``events[i].getComments,()events[i].getDetails()``. How about modifying to ``events[i].getComments(),events[i].getDetails()``?